# Reading & Interpreting Binary file in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, hex, qbytearray

Trying to read a binary file in Qt.

The file has mixed text and binary (hex) data.

THe file contains regions of data with the lengths specified by hex numbers.

For example:

`00 01 BE 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01`

Here "BE" is at offset BB in the file. BE is 190, so I scroll forward to the last byte above and I know the next 190 bytes are my data.

I've been struggling for a couple of days trying to get my Qt code convert the Byte value "BE" as above to the number 190.

The best I get is "-66", which is of course 190-256.

Another example is:

`00 01 D3 63 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01`

Should be converted to "63D3" which is 25555 decimal.

Here are my code snippets:

1. Read  the file:

   ```
   QFile file(iFile);
   if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) return;
   QByteArray iContents = file.readAll();
   ```
2. Get the length

   ```
   ushort  c3 = 0xFF;
   c3 = iContents.at(2); // c3 should be "BE" hex.
   printf ( "%0x %d\n", c3, c3 );
   ```

Output is :

`FFFFFFBE -66`

How do I get this is be read as 190?

I've tried various things after searching but nothing seems to work which suggest I am missing something basic in my code.

Current code to do the conversion is:decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QByteArray::at()` returns a (signed) `char` and you assign it to an `unsigned short`. You want the value 0xbe to be treated as unsigned, so you should cast it :
`c3 = (unsigned char) iContents.at(2);`

For the 2 bytes little-endian integer (I assume it's just `D363` you are interested in and the zeros are meaningless here ?):

`unsigned short i = (unsigned char) iContent.at(2) | (unsigned char) iContent.at(3) << 8;`

The `(unsigned char)` cast has highest precedence, and the operands of bitwise operators are promoted to integers (this is why the shift result isn't zero).

Comment: May I ask, what would be the "Correct" way to take the following byte sequence "D3 63 00 00 00 00 00 00 00" and change it to 0x63D3. This was the second part of my question.

I am think along the lines of take byte 1 (D3) and convert that, then the 2nd byte (63) and convert that then ans = num1 + num2*(16^2), but this seems really clunky.

Comment: @TenG I assumed you don't care about the zeros ? Edited.